# Matlab syms for linearization of bilinear expressions

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, nonlinear-functions, linearization

I have a system of nonlinear(bilinear) equations and would like to linearize it in most automated way. I thought that i could use syms for this task, for sure not only way to do this, could you share your experience how to do this.

```
syms  f1(x1,x2,u1,u2,u3) f2(x1,u1)

f1(x1,x2,u1,u2,u3)= u1x1 + u2(u3-x2);
f2(x1,u1)= u1x1;
```

Comment: It is very unclear. You have a big task and you just dumped a huge pile of code here. It is unlikely someone will go thourgh all the code and solve it for you, its just too much. Can you make this problem way more simpler, using very easy sample equations and way less variables? that will help you to get help from people

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i have downsized the problem.

Comment: So you want to compute f2 from f1 programatically?

Comment: As i have mentioned i want to linearize those equations.

Comment: What is to linearize? What would be the desired result? show us how to linearize `f2`, and we will help you to get it done programatically.